# How to base64 encode a picture for twitter in python?

Tags: python, twitter, base64, twython

So I have been trying, (without luck) to base64 encode a image to upload to twitter with the Twython library. Iv'e done it the way I know how but it don't seem to work.

```
from twython import Twython
import base64

#keys
APP_KEY = '*************'
APP_SECRET = '**************'
OAUTH_TOKEN = '**********************'
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = '*************************'
#start twitter instance
twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)

#encode image to bas64
with open("image.jpeg", "rb") as imageF:
    st = base64.b64encode(imageF.read())
    #print to make sure its being encoded
    print st

#update twitter banner
twitter.update_profile_background_image(image=st)
```

The twitter docs don't help to much. https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/account/update_profile_banner 
Nor does the Twython Docs. https://twython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html 
Let me know how you would do it. Or if you have a better way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I thought I would come back and say what I found out. The way I was doing it works. I apparently had made the same call with invalid parameters before and twitter much count all API calls as a call. And they seem to not let you make a banner update call very often. Also I think they expect the image to be the right size, which seems to be(1500px,500px) So you should try to resize the image before you encode it. If someone knows of a simpler way...i'm still open for suggestions.

Thanks for now!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is 'banner' instead of 'image'

```
twitter.update_profile_background_image(banner=st)
```

Comment: That would make more sence...but it still don't want to work. I think I must be encoding it wrong.

Comment: Its returning a (Unprocessable Entity) I think that twitter is rejecting the type of encoding. I'm not sure though.

Comment: in twitter, that error means 'The image could not be resized or is too large'

Comment: Well, I don't really understand what is happening. I resized the image and called (image=st) and it worked in a way. It didn't have it positioned properly. It put it clear up in the corner and most of the space stayed blank. I stilled think its not being encoded properly. Is they another way to encode I wonder?

Comment: The correct parameter to pass for the twython method:  `update_profile_background_image` isn't `banner`, it is `image`...  If you were using the `update_profile_banner_image` method, it would be `banner`, but that isn't the question.